# Jasmine AngularJS : Mock a $scope property?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've got an AngularJS controller like that :

```
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myFactory){  
            $scope.types = myFactory.getTypes();    
            $scope.model= {};    
            $scope.model.type = $scope.types[0].type;

    });
});
```

Everything works fine.

But i want to test this controller in Jasmine. 
So i mock `myFactory` and init `myCtrl` like that:

```
 describe('Controllers: MyCtrl', function () {

        var MyCtrl, mockedFactory, scope;

        beforeEach(module('app.factories', function ($provide) {
            mockedFactory = {
                getTypes: function(){}
            };

            spyOn(mockedFactory, 'getTypes');
            $provide.value('myFactory', mockedFactory);
        }));

        beforeEach(module('app'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            MyCtrl= $controller('MyCtrl', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should call AccordTypeFactory.getAvailableTypes()', function () {
            scope.types;
            expect(mockedFactory.getTypes).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

But i've got a logic bug : `Cannot read property 0 of undefined`

I understand this bug; because i mock the factory my controller property `$scope.model.type` it's undefined because it use the result of the factory through `$scope.types`.

My question is simple: How can i make work my test ?

Thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found better solution than andCallThrough i think.

It's imple i have just to add andReturn function after spyOn :

```
spyOn(mockedFactory, 'getTypes').andReturn([{type: 'MockType'}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    beforeEach(module('app.factories', function ($provide) {
        mockedFactory = {
            getTypes: function(){ return [{}]; }
        };

        spyOn(mockedFactory, 'getTypes').andCallThrough();
        $provide.value('myFactory', mockedFactory);
    }));
```

If I understood you correctly your problem is that the mock does not return an array while your controller expects there to always be at least 1 element in it. You could set up the mock to return an array with an element and then use `andCallThrough()` on the spy to have it actually call the mock.

If it possible that your factory can return empty arrays while the application is running, you'd probably want to check that the array contains at least one element before trying to access `types[0]`